# Restrictions accessing Google Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

Requirement was to host an application that will be accessed from multiple geographies including China.

Google App Engine was proposed for application hosting with data storage in Google Cloud SQL for relational data and Google Cloud Storage for binary content.

Understand that applications hosted on Google App Engine cannot be accessed from China (without using other products like Appscale).

if the application is deployed on Google Compute Engine instead of Google App Engine, can the application continue to use Google Cloud SQL and cloud storage and still be functional when accessed from China?

Looking forward for inputs / pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable api for your require things from your account. And you can use Google SQL and Cloud Stroage and will get full functionality when using google compute engine.

Comment: There are restrictions only if these services are accessed directly from China. There are no restrictions as such for Google Cloud SQL and Google Cloud Storage if they are called via compute engine. Is this a fair understanding?